# Task.Any() Call task twice

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am running task like below.

```
var tasks = from job in jobs select ProcessFile(job);
```

where ProcessFile is a method which return bool Task

```
private async Task<bool> ProcessFile(Job job)
```

Now weird thing is that i want to check if any of the task result was  true or not like below.

```
 await Task.WhenAll(tasks);    
 var isTrueForAny =tasks.Any(x => x.Result == true);
```

But at this point my method ProcessFile(job) is called again though i have only one job. Could you guys help me understand what is the reason?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is lazy. Every time you iterate over it, it will call `ProcessFile` again. You probably want to make `tasks` a `List<Task<bool>>`, by adding an appropriate call to `ToList()`

Comment: @canton7 probably no need to create a list, just use `Task.WhenAll` directly.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay It properly explains the reason, which your answer currently doesn't.

Comment: @GSerg I don't disagree with the reasoning.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yeah I forgot it did that - your answer is good. My comment does explain (albeit briefly) why the issue occurs, and a general solution to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);    
bool isTrueForAny = results.Any(b => b);
```

Awaiting `Task.WhenAll` unwraps the task results into an array, which you can test using `Any()`.

Calling `Any()` directly on the `IEnumerable` will cause the iterator to be re run, which is why `ProcessFile` is being called again.

Answer (score 4):

The reason of that behaviour is ***Deferred Execution***.

> Deferred execution means that the evaluation of an expression is
>   delayed until its realized value is actually required.

Let's take a look step by step:

```
 var tasks = from job in jobs select ProcessFile(job);
```

See value of the `tasks` variable as sql query. It will be executed every time when you are trying to use `tasks` variable in places where value of that query is needed.

First time that "query" will be executed while awaiting that tasks.

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

And second time, when you are iterating over the result of that `query`. Though, not all tasks will be executed twice as `Any` will stop iterating as soon as it findsfirst matched task.

```
 var isTrueForAny =tasks.Any(x => x.Result == true);
```

Take a look to [***`Deferred Execution`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution) concept in LINQ.

For solving the issue you need to force ***immediate execution***.To force immediate execution of a query that does not produce a singleton value, you can call the `ToList` method, the `ToDictionary` method, or the `ToArray` method on a query or query variable. But, it will be problematic as you are projecting `Task` object from your collection. You can get around of that issue by just creating extension method `ToListAsync`.

Or for solving the issue, you just need to change your code in a way, that you iterates over collection only once. (as @Johnathan already offered to you in his answer)

Comment: This answer is clear explanation of problem i was not understanding. But  I have already accepted the first answer. Thank you so much again for your clear explanation.

Comment: @Amir No, problem as he already proposed solution, I tried to explain the reason.